# Multi level list based on array of void pointers

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have written code, but I don't like it, it seems very ungeneralized. I want to make it more abstract and universal and independent of type.

I have the task to write programm, which can operate with multi level list. List should be done on array of void pointers. Data structure should be roughly like on the picture: [image]

I have made this on classes. I have separate class `pointerArray`, which operates with array of void pointers. But I didn't hit upon the idea how to make generalized class  (which doesn't depend of structure type), namely how to do delete function which doesn't depend on structure type. So I have made it template class.

But the main thing, which I don't like is: if I need to add element to the lowest level of list I should step by step cast types to reach lowest level.

For this program maybe it isn't so important, but I have to make same list for more than 5 levels.

So, please, look through, comment and suggest what to change or how to realise this task in another way. Here this sources on [github](https://github.com/CROSP/VoidArrayList)
**WITHOUT USING STANDARD CLASSES** (like `<vector>` and so on)
Here is some part of code 
pointerArray.h

```
 #ifndef POINTERARRAY_H
#define POINTERARRAY_H
#define DEF_SIZE (10)
#define DELTA (4)

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;



typedef
int (*TCmpFunc)(void*, string);

template <class T>
class pointerArray {
public:
    pointerArray(int initialSize = DEF_SIZE){
           this->start = new void* [initialSize]; /* запрашиваем память для  нового массива*/
           this->initArr(initialSize);
    }
    void showList();
    bool delFromList(int posDel);
    int findElList(string key, TCmpFunc cmpF,bool &findOK);
    void addToSort(void* pnew, int posAdd);
    void replaceSort(int delPos, void* newEl, int inPos);
    void clearAll();
    bool delAllList(bool delPointers);
    void expandDef(int sizeOld, int incSize);
    void** getStart() {
        return this->start;
    };
    int getSize() {
        return this->size;
    };
    int getCount() {
        return this->count;
    }
    void* getElem(int posEl) {
        return this->start[posEl];
    }
    ~pointerArray() {
        this->delAllList(true);
    };

protected:
    int size;
    int count;
    void** start;
    void initArr(int initSize);

};

 template<class T> void pointerArray<T>::initArr(int initSize) {
    this->count = 0;

    this->size = initSize; 

 template<class T> void pointerArray<T>::expandDef(int sizeOld, int incSize = DELTA) {

    int sizeNew = sizeOld + incSize;
    void** arOld = this->start; 
    this->start = new void* [sizeNew]; 


    for (int i = sizeOld-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        this->start[i] = arOld[i];
    }
    this->size = sizeNew;

    delete []arOld;
}

 template<class T> int pointerArray<T>::findElList(string key,TCmpFunc cmpF,bool &findOK) {

    int posFndEl;
    int middl; 
    int hi, low; 



    if (this->count == 0) {
        posFndEl = 0;
        return posFndEl;
    }

    low = 0;
    hi = this->count - 1;

    do {

      middl = (hi + low) / 2 ; 



   int   resultCompare= cmpF(this->start[middl], key); 

      if (resultCompare== 0)
        { posFndEl = middl; 
        findOK = true;      
        return posFndEl;
        }
     if (resultCompare == 1)
        {
          hi = middl - 1;  
       }
     else 
        {
         low = middl + 1;
       } 


    } while (low <= hi);
    findOK = false;
    posFndEl = low;
    return posFndEl;
}

 template<class T> void pointerArray<T>::replaceSort(int delPos, void* newEl,int inPos) {
    this->delFromList(delPos);
    this->addToSort(newEl,inPos);
}

 template<class T> void pointerArray<T>::clearAll() {
    this->delFromList(0);
}

 template<class T> bool pointerArray<T>::delFromList(int posDel) {
    int cnt = this->count;
    if ((posDel < 0) || (posDel>cnt)) {
        return false;
    }
    delete (T*)(this->start[posDel]);
    for (int k = posDel; k < cnt - 1; k++) {
        this->start[k] = this->start[k + 1];
    }
    cnt--;
    this->count = cnt;
}

 template<class T> bool pointerArray<T>::delAllList(bool delPointers) {
    int cnt = this->count;
    if ((cnt==0) && (!delPointers)) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i=0;i<cnt-1;i++) {
        delete (T*)(this->start[i]);
    }
    if (delPointers) {
        delete []this->start;
        this->start = NULL;
        this->size = 0;

    }
    this->count = 0;
    return true;
}

 template<class T> void pointerArray<T>::addToSort(void* pnew, int posAdd) {


    int cnt = this->count;
    int sz = this->size;


    if (cnt == sz) {
        this->expandDef(this->size);
    }


    if (posAdd == cnt) 
    {
        this->start[posAdd] = pnew;
    } else { // сдвиг элементов в массиве указателей на 1 вправо
        for (int k = cnt - 1; k >= posAdd; k--) {
            this->start[k + 1] = this->start[k];
        }
        this->start[posAdd] = pnew;
    }
    cnt++;

    this->count = cnt;
}

#endif // POINTERARRAY_H
```

And mainUniv

```
/* 
 * File:   mainUniv.cpp
 * Author: CROSP
 * 
 * Created on October 16, 2013, 8:50 PM
 */

#include "mainUniv.h"

mainUniv::mainUniv() {
    this->univPoint = 0;
}

bool mainUniv::addUniv(void* pNew, string name) {
    bool success;
    this->univPoint->addToSort(pNew,this->univPoint->findElList(name, cmpUniv, success));
}

void* mainUniv::getUniv(string name, bool &findOk) {
    int posUniv = (this->univPoint->findElList(name, cmpUniv, findOk));
    if (findOk) {
        return (this->univPoint->getElem(posUniv));

    }
    else return 0;
}

        void* mainUniv::getFaculty(void* unPoint, string facName,bool &findOk) {
            TUniver * tmpUn = (TUniver*)unPoint;
            if (tmpUn->subInit) {
               int fndPos = tmpUn->sublev->findElList(facName, cmpFact,findOk);
               if (findOk) {
            return tmpUn->sublev->getElem(fndPos);
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
  }
          void* mainUniv::getChair(void* unFac, string facName,bool &findOk) {
            TFaculty *tmpFac = (TFaculty*)unFac;
            if (tmpFac->subInit) {
               int fndPos = tmpFac->sublev->findElList(facName, cmpFact,findOk);
               if (findOk) {
            return tmpFac->sublev->getElem(fndPos);
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
  }

bool mainUniv::addFaculty(void* pNew, void *univP, string facName) {
       TUniver *tmpUniv = (TUniver*)(univP);
            bool findFac = false;
            if (!(tmpUniv->subInit)) {
            this->initFac(tmpUniv);
            }
            tmpUniv->sublev->addToSort(pNew, tmpUniv->sublev->findElList(facName, cmpFact, findFac));
            return true;
    }
    bool mainUniv::initFac(void* tmpUn) {
        TUniver* tnp =(TUniver*)tmpUn;
        tnp->sublev= new pointerArray<TFaculty>();
        tnp->subInit = true;
        return true;
    }

    pointerArray<TUniver>* mainUniv::getUnivStart() {
        return this->univPoint;
    }   

    bool mainUniv::initChair(void* fac) {
        TFaculty* tmpFac = (TFaculty*)(fac);
        tmpFac->sublev = new pointerArray<TChair>();
        tmpFac->subInit = true;
        return true;
    }
    bool mainUniv::addChair(void* fac,void *pnew,string name) {
        TFaculty *tmpFac = (TFaculty*)fac;
        bool findOk;
         if (!(tmpFac->subInit)) {
            this->initChair(tmpFac);
            }
        tmpFac->sublev->addToSort(pnew,tmpFac->sublev->findElList(name,cmpChr,findOk));
    }
        void ** mainUniv::createUnivArr(int inSize) {
            this->univPoint = new pointerArray<TUniver>(inSize);
            return this->univPoint->getStart();
        }

        void mainUniv::delChair(void *pFac,int delPos) {
            TFaculty *tmpF = (TFaculty*)pFac;
            tmpF->sublev->delFromList(delPos);

        }
        bool mainUniv::delFaculty(void *pUniv,string delFac)
        {
            TUniver* tmpUn = (TUniver*)pUniv;
            if (!tmpUn->subInit) {
                return false ;
            }
            bool find;
            TFaculty *tmpFac =(TFaculty*)this->getFaculty(pUniv,delFac,find);
            if (!find) {
                return false;
            }
            if (tmpFac->subInit) {
                this->delAllChairs(tmpFac,true);
            }
            tmpUn->sublev->delFromList(tmpUn->sublev->findElList(delFac,cmpFact,find));
            return true;
        }
        bool mainUniv::delAllFaculties(void *pUniv,bool delPointers) {
            TUniver *tmpUn = (TUniver*)pUniv;
            if (tmpUn->subInit) {
                int cnt = tmpUn->sublev->getCount();
                TFaculty* tmFac;
                for (int i=0;i<cnt;i++) {
                    tmFac =(TFaculty*)(tmpUn->sublev->getElem(i));
                    if (tmFac->subInit) {
                    this->delAllChairs(tmFac,true);
                    }
                }
                    tmpUn->sublev->delAllList(delPointers);
                    if (delPointers) {
                        delete tmpUn->sublev;
                        tmpUn->subInit = false;
                    }
            } else 
            {return false;}
        }
         bool mainUniv::delAllChairs(void *pFac,bool delPointers) {
           TFaculty *tmpF = (TFaculty*)pFac;
            tmpF->sublev->delAllList(delPointers);
            if (delPointers) {
            delete tmpF->sublev;
            tmpF->subInit = false;
            }   
         }
         bool mainUniv::delAllUniver(bool delPointers) {
             if (!this->univPoint) {
             return false;
             }
             int unCnt = this->univPoint->getCount();
             for (int i=0;i<unCnt;i++) {
                 this->delAllFaculties(this->univPoint->getElem(i),true);
             }
             this->univPoint->delAllList(delPointers);
             if (delPointers){ 
                 delete this->univPoint;
             }
         }
         bool mainUniv::delUniv(string name) {
             if (!this->univPoint) {
                 return false;
             }
             bool fndOk;
             int delPos = this->univPoint->findElList(name,cmpUniv,fndOk);
             if (fndOk) {
                 this->delUniv(delPos);
                 return true;
             } else return false;

         }
         bool mainUniv::delUniv(int delPos) {
             TUniver *unDel = (TUniver*)this->univPoint->getElem(delPos);
             if(unDel->subInit) {
                 this->delAllFaculties(unDel,true);
             }
             this->univPoint->delFromList(delPos);
             return true;
         }
```

Comment: Linking to GitHub is helpful, but by the rules of this site, you must include code to be reviewed in the question itself, or at least the most important parts of the code. Also, if you link to GitHub, you should point to a specific commit, otherwise the reviews here won't make sense after you revise the code there.

Comment: I have only one commit in this represitory , here is link https://github.com/CROSP/VoidArrayList/commit/46ee3995f37ac655da588d6ef9608d22e9e0bd66

Answer (score 2):

This looks a lot like *c with classes* rather than *c++*.

1. If you are using void pointers in C++, you are probably doing something wrong. You `pointerArray` class is templated, but you don't use the templates at all.
2. A class name should begin with a capital letter.
3. Use a function object (functor) instead of a function pointer.
4. You don't have a destructor for `pointerArray`. If an exception is thrown, you'll probably have a memory leak.

Here's a basic idea of what you may want to do instead:

```
#define DEF_SIZE 10
#define DELTA 4

template <typename T>
struct SampleCompareFunctor
{
    bool operator () (const T &lhs, const T &rhs) const {
        return lhs < rhs ;
    }
};

template <typename T>
class Array
{
public:
    Array (const size_t initial_size = DEF_SIZE) ;
    ~Array () ;

    void insertValue (const size_t index, const T &val) ;
    T removeValue (const size_t index) ;

    // Getters, so you could do Array a ;  a [0] ....
    T& operator [] (const size_t index) ;
    const T& operator [] (const size_t index) const ;

    template <typename CompareFunctor>
    void sort () ;

//...

private:
    T *m_data ;
};

template <typename T>
Array <T>::Array (const size_t initial_size) : m_data (new T [initial_size])
{
}

template <typename T>
Array <T>::~Array ()
{
    delete [] m_data ;
    m_data = nullptr ; // Or NULL if you don't have c++11
}

template <typename T>
T& Array <T>::operator [] (const size_t index)
{
    return m_data [index] ;
}

template <typename T>
const T& Array <T>::operator [] (const size_t index) const
{
    return m_data [index] ;
}

template <typename T>
template <typename CompareFunctor>
void Array <T>::sort ()
{
    // Implement your sorting function here.
}
```

This is just a partial review. I haven't looked at the rest yet.